# Algorithms suited for Traversing locations for optimized path

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am developing an Application which will allocate Cabs to the Employees.The pickup location will be office location for everyone and Drop Location can be any location in the City.Which algorithm like BFS, DFS can i use which will give me the optimized path which will help me to optimize the cost Expenditure.
Any Suggestion is Welcome and highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem, as stated, is too short of details to be given a specific answer. Some general pointers follow that may be helpful.

There is a class of problems within [Vehicle Routing Problem literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem) that deals with [pickup and delivery problems](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/42371592/PDPsurveyPart2_web.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1511269526&Signature=dJkztUwbbxOFOXpIgtnUhOlb9Wg%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DA_survey_on_pickup_and_delivery_problems.pdf).

Within these problems, there are problems further classified based on whether or not there exist time windows for pickup and/or delivery.

None of the simple algorithms you have in mind BFS/DFS can give you an optimized solution since the Vehicle Routing Problem is rather difficult to solve practically. It is NP-Hard. The Travelling Salesman Problem is a special case of the Vehicle Routing Problem.